# Align icons at left and Right corner of navbar of jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm using below code to add nav bar to my mobile website. Here I have two icon on the left side of nav bar. But I want to position the Next icon to the Right Side such that Two icon will be on corner of left and Right Side.

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
  

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>


 




    <div data-role="page">      

   
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-theme="a">
            <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="left">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#one" data-icon="arrow-l" >Previous</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#two" data-icon="arrow-r" >Next</a></li>
                   
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /navbar -->                             
        </div> 

    </div>
```

Here is the picture, I'd like to get the output[image]

For some Reason the code is not working , So here is the link for my demo snippet
[Demo Snippets](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JpjLBE)

Comment: where are your icons??

Comment: @Bhuwan, I don't know why it's not showing here. Any way I've created a snippets on Codepen with above code...Here is the link https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JpjLBE . Hope it'll help you.

Comment: same college course ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48353947/how-to-align-icons-at-left-and-right-corner-of-navbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add some css fo this

```
.ui-block-b a .ui-btn-inner .ui-icon{
  left: auto;
  right: 5px;
}
```

**[Updated Codepen](https://codepen.io/bhuwanb9/pen/VQwXgy)**

Comment: Glad to help..!